# Hyper-V virtualization type

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Does Hyper-v Server 2012 R2 use para-virtualization or Full hardware virtualization? The server I want to virtualize has 36 cores, 32 of those cores need to be dedicated to one VM that does a lot of computations. Will I be able to use Hyper-V and use the other 4 cores without it affecting the performance of the main VM and it not being slowed down by the main VM?

Also, would it make a difference to use Hyper-v server or the hyper-v role in server 2012 r2?

Comment: We do expect you to do your homework before asking.  Your first and last questions would be answered by reading the basic literature.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V offers both full hardware virtualization and paravirtualization to its guest VMs.  Which one you use depends on what you install in the guest.  With Windows guests, this is either a matter of installing the Integration Services in the guest (by telling Hyper-V to insert the IC DVD-ROM image into the virtual DVD drive) or, for Server 2012 R2 guests, just going to Windows Update.  For Linux guests, it depends on what version you're using and whether that version has picked up a recent enough kernel to have the right drivers.  The list of supported Linuxes is on Microsoft's web sites.